# Lines were dropped when merging two text files using the write() method

Tags: python

I started with relevant_files, which was a list of paths of two CSV files. I then attempted to create a file with path output_filename, using the following block of code.

```py
new_file = open(output_filename, 'w+')
for x in relevant_files:
    for line in open(x):
        new_file.write(line)
```

The code looks perfectly reasonable, but I totally randomly decided to check the lengths, before and after the merge. file_1 had length 6,740,108 and file_2 had length 4,938,459. Those sum to 11,678,567. However, the new file has length 11,678,550, which is 17 lines shorter than the combined length of the two source files. I then checked the CSV files by hand -- indeed, it was exactly the final 17 lines of the 2nd text file (i.e., 2nd entry in relevant_files) that had gotten dropped.

What went wrong? Is there a maximum file length or something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with your script, but it's good to use `with` statements when working with files in python. They get rid of the need to close the file once you've opened it, which it seems you haven't done here.

```
with open(output_file, 'w+') as f:
    lines = []
    for file in relevant_files:
        for line in open(file, 'r').read().split('\n'):
            lines.append(line)
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

This is what I would use to complete your task.

Comment: (1) Can you edit your code so that it doesn't toss in an extraneous blank line in the new file between the contents of the 1st file and the contents of 2nd file? (2) Can you remark on memory usage, comparing my original approach (which was incorrect but can perhaps be adapted) to your approach? That is, I think my approach only stores one line at a time into memory, while I think yours is creating this list which ultimately has one entire source file at a time in memory (in its inner for-loop).

Comment: To demonstrate how the extraneous empty line is appearing, I made a text file with 2 lines, and ran the following code on it:

lines = []
with open('test2.txt') as x:
    for line in x.read().split('\n'):
        lines.append(line)
        print(lines)


This gave the following output:


['asdfasdfasdf']
['asdfasdfasdf', 'vasd']
['asdfasdfasdf', 'vasd', '']

Comment: I don't actually understand why it's adding that empty string onto the list.

Comment: Note also that, in your original solution, there was no empty line at the end of the combined file. Just one in the middle of it, where the 1st file's contents ended and the 2nd one's began. This is further confusing, since the behavior I've demonstrated with my two-line text file would lead you to think that every file is picking up an empty string as its final entry into the ```lines``` list.

Comment: It is possible that you have empty lines at the ends of you files. If so, use the ```strip()``` method to remove them. As for memory, I don't know how to write to a file line by line, though i think the csv module has a function that would be useful to you.

Comment: I verified that I don't have empty lines at the end of my original files, so no need to use strip(). I edited one line in your code and changed it to: lines.append(line) if line!='' else 3.141592. This works, even if I'm not totally sure why I had to do it.